# Why can I programmatically connect to my Visual Studio Online Project without Credentials?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I have a ASP.NET application and wanted to display the last few changesets on a Page. With this Code I get the latest Changesets:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection
    = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("https://my.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"));
var versionControl = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var history = versionControl.QueryHistory(
        path: "$/project",
        version: VersionSpec.Latest,
        deletionId: 0,
        recursion: RecursionType.Full,
        user: String.Empty,
        versionFrom: null,
        versionTo: VersionSpec.Latest,
        maxCount: 5,
        includeChanges: false,
        slotMode: true);

foreach (Changeset change in history)
{
    [...]
}
```

I didn't expect it to work at first, but then it worked like a charm, without Credentials. This makes me slightly nervous as I didn't change any Permissions on the project let alone make it "public" (if this is even possible).
If I browse to the Project anonymously in a Browser I have to Login with my Live-ID.

So can anyone access my data if he has the adress? And how can I disable this?

Comment: Are you testing your asp.net application locally and running it as yourself? odds are it's simply using your cached credentials from your last connection. If it works when you deploy on a server from which you never logged into your Microsoft account then that becomes worrysome. Also if you linked your Microsoft and local account (default on Windows 8+) and that account is the one that has the credential to access your TFS and also the one running the website, it sounds perfectly normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a cookie authenticating you to VSOnline.  Try logging out in your browser and you'll note that you cannot authenticate with your code.

You need to set up alternate credentials in order to authenticate programmatically:  http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/get-started-auth-introduction-vsi

Comment: @Edward:  I have  a similar question for VS2017 where some users are being prompted and others are not even though we are all signed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098682/tfs-online-programmatic-access-is-working-for-some-users-without-credentials-w