# Team Services programmatic access is working for some users without credentials - why?

Tags: azure-devops

We have recently upgraded to VS 2017 and Visual Studio Team Services.

We have a set of automated tools that perform various source control related tasks on behalf of developers.

Some users and one service account appear to have cached credentials somewhere and do not get prompted for credentials when running the tools.

However, other users get prompted for credentials.

I created a mini test app to illustrate the issue.  NOTE:  The VSTS dlls are the version 15.x files from the VS2017 Team Explorer installation folder.  They are also available as part of the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient NuGet package if you don't mind the bloat.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace VSTSTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                if (args.Length > 0)
                {
                    var projectCollectionUrl = args[0];

                    var projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(projectCollectionUrl));
                    var versionControlServer = (VersionControlServer)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

                    Console.WriteLine("AuthorizedUser: {0}", versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Usage is {projectCollectionUrl}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This works for some users but not for others and I am trying to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this registry path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp` (Tested in VS2017, it stores in 14.0 too)

You also can check credential manager.

On the other hand, you can change storage key:

```
var c = new VssClientCredentials();
c.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(storageKind: "VssApp2", storageNamespace: "VisualStudio");
TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I can confirm that the differences between the users that get prompted and those that do not is that registry key.  Can you explain a little about what is going on?  Or point me at the documentation?  I would like to understand when some of our devs have this key and others do not.

Comment: Ideally I would prefer our devs to be able to access without PAT (which require an additional management step of creating a PAT).  Does the code you posted allow this?  I don't have the registry key.  Would that code stop me getting the prompt?

Comment: With the code that I provided, it will prompt the window for loging if there isn't the related key in registry.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I asked in the question.  I wanted to know why some devs have this key and others do not?  What is creating the key?  We all connect to VS2017 in the same way via the log on prompt.  Why do some of us have a key and others do not?  Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: Actually the question title just asks why.  You've explained why just not the why of the why :).  I will mark as answer.

Comment: I have cleared out confusing info from the question.  I will ask another question about why some users have the key and others do not.  That you for your help.

Comment: This question explains where the key comes from:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535724/vsts-authenticating-with-vssclientcredentials