# How to clear credential cache by CredentialProvider.VSS.exe

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

I made a NuGet feed at [Azure Artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/). I installed `NuGet.exe` and `CredentialProvider.VSS.exe` into my project. I can list/get/push NuGet packages. At this time, no problem at all. But I want to clear my credential cache that created by `CredentialProvider.VSS.exe`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to clear my credential cache that created by CredentialProvider.VSS.exe. How can I do that?

CredentialProvider.VSS.exe stores and uses the credential in the registry path. 
If you want to clear credential, you could remove the token value from registry.

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp\{xxxx}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Thank you! How do you know that?  I can't find any information about this!

Comment: `How do you know that?`  I also try lots of ways to clear the credential, at last I got the idea from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098682/team-services-programmatic-access-is-working-for-some-users-without-credentials?rq=1). And based on my test, it works.

Comment: Didn't work for me; deleted this key, cleared all nuget caches, restarted computer, re-built locally - and nuget just authenticates and downloads from the private feed. God knows how...

Comment: Token key not present on my Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022 machine.

Comment: I can't find the Token key on my machine

Answer (score 0):

[`nuget.exe locals plugins-cache -clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/tools/cli-ref-locals) should do it. You'll need to [download nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) if you haven't already. Unfortunately the plugins-cache appears to be missing from `dotnet nuget locals` :(

Comment: I tried.  Even the plugins-cache been cleared.  It still can't login as another person.  It's authenticated automatically. :(